# Fragments overlap on OnBackPress in Navigation Drawer/Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I am new in Android and I work with fragments. I am using Navigation Drawer Activity with fragments. All the code is working fine. But the problem is when I navigate to multiple fragments and open fragment from navigation drawer, and press back button, fragments overlap on each-other. And all the fragments repeat as I open them one by one.
I am using this code for navigation:
This is my HomeFragment Code

```
requests.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            ConrequestsFragment fragment = new ConrequestsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

[image: Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happens only when I navigate from Navigation drawer to different fragments. I found the solution and add this code into my ***MainActivity.java***
Here is code:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_status, R.id.nav_package,R.id.nav_contact)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull
                NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {

            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_profile) {
                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }

            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_status) {
                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }

            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_package) {

                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
            if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_contact) {

                int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
                    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give white background to your xml layout in fragments and also use android:clickable="true" & android:focusable="true".Try this and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: its overlapping still now, it just changed the background color of the top fragment.